# How to calculate the differential coefficient in c

Tags: c, math, numerical-methods, derivative, differentiation

Thanks a lot people for your help so far but I made a big mistake I need the derivation of a function at a specific point!

*I have to calculate the first derivation of a function and I really have no clue how to get there. If I just had to calculate it for a function with just a X^1 I would know how to but I'm really stuck here.*

Old Stuff:
A function can look like `2*x^2+1`.

The method has to look like this: `double ab(double (f)(double),double x)`
and my professor gave us the hint that we might should use the function:
`(f(x0+∆x)−f(x0))/((x0+∆x)−x0)`.

Sorry for my bad English and thanks for any kind of hint or tip in advance.

Comment: Take delta=0.01 and try to implement the formula you gave.

Comment: Suppose you wanted to approximate the derivative of a function by hand. How would you do that?

Comment: What does your function look like? You say its just X^1 which seems to imply it is a linear function `a x + b`. If so the derivative is just `a`. You can prove this from first principles putting the values `x0+∆x` and `x0` into the equation.

Comment: It has to be able to work with all kind of functions so there is no specific one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this sample will get you started :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


float func(float x)
{
    return(2*x*x + 1);
}

int main(){
    float h=0.01;
    float x;
    float deriv, second;

    printf("Enter x value: ");
    scanf("%f", &x);
    // derivative at x is the slope of infinitely small
    // line of the function 

    deriv = (func(x+h) - func(x))/h; // I assumed the length to be h

    //for second derivative you can use:
    second = (func(x+h) - 2*func(x) + func(x-h))/(h*h);

    printf("%f\n", deriv);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I once had it like that but thought it was wrong because I had no mathematical reference but I just found a reference thanks to NPEs link and thanks to you I had a code reference. Now I also understand what I did wrong in the first place besides from the wrong description. And I would really like to give both of you a correct answer but so I will have to flip a coin :D

Comment: @chouaib Do you maybe also know how to make it so that it also works for the second derivation?

Comment: @Akkyen I used `(f(x+h)-f(x))/h` for first derivative, you can use `(f(x+h) - 2f(x) + f(x-h))/h*h` for second order and so on ...

Comment: @duffymo: no it is not wrong! I said this is a **SAMPLE** not a **SOLUTION** so I can use any sample function to demonstrate the way to solve it. after that it's up to him to understand and change what's necissary to have his desired solution

Comment: Since he explicitly asked for 2*x*x+1, I assumed that you'd follow suit with his example.  A student who fails to understand this simple idea might be silly enough to cut & paste code without looking at it.  I understand your point, though.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is approximate the first derivative of `f()` at `x` with the slope of the secant line through the points  `(x, f(x))` and `(x+∆x, f(x+∆x))`.

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation) should get you started.